# How to change a specific parameter in the UR with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url:

> http://www.site.com/?option=com_php&Itemid=143&ep3[]=%3Fsid%3Dodp22rjt7glclu1hshb2gc5va7gjuv4c%26lang%3Den%26sd%3D11.09.2012%26ed%3D05.10.2012%26tt%3DF%26sp%3D3%26st%3DPA

I want to replace another string in this url eg:

`"option=com_php&Itemid=143"` to `"catalog"`

`"sp%3D3%26st%3DPA"` to `"phone"`

`"tt%3DF%26"` to `"windows"`

etc.

I want to this url:

> http://www.site.com/?catalog&ep3[]=%3Fsid%3Dodp22rjt7glclu1hshb2gc5va7gjuv4c%26lang%3Den%26sd%3D11.09.2012%26ed%3D05.10.2012%26&windows&phone

or something.

I want to change a specific parameter in the URL for the product name, eg

I have read many responses on this subject and I searched the web, but unfortunately no solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `%{QUERY_STRING}`, I will just give you an example on how it works :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?param1=value(&.*)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1replacement%2 [L]
```

The %n (where n is a number) is used to capture the values between parentheses in the last rewrite condition, the $n (where n is a number too) is used to capture the values between parentheses in the rewrite rule.